# Reducing FFmpeg dlls to only what is used?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I have written Windows software that calls the FFmpeg dlls to encode a sequence of images in a few different formats (animated gif, animated png, mpeg4, wmv, webm). I need to provide the dlls with my software but they significantly increase the download size. Even after zipping everything they increase the size from around 5MB to around 20MB. This isn't a huge problem but I'd like to get the download size down as much as possible.

How easy is it to do this and by roughly how much would I be able to reduce them? Note that I don't need any decoders and am only encoding those 5 formats. I'm not using any special filters and the encoded videos don't have sound. I'd like to know if it's worth it before I start trying to compile the FFmpeg source and playing with configuration flags.

Comment: Doesn't Windows already provide encodes for all of those formats?

Comment: I'm not sure about all of them. Possibly. I do know that Windows has it's own video encoders but using them is not straightforward. Code libraries exist for calling FFmeg but not Windows (I'm developing in Delphi FMX). My app will also run on other platforms in future.

Comment: If you are targeting multiple platforms, you're probably forced into using a library (no matter how much it sucks). Shrinking a DLL is *technically* possible, though entirely non-trivial (and quite likely not provably to be correct). The easiest route would be to compile from source. "Easiest" may still be hard, depending on how intimate you are with [your linker](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/tag/linker).

Comment: There are many answers here that show how to make a custom ffmpeg that does only a few things. File size reduction may be significant, but it's not easy to understand which configure options you need. So it will result in many trial-and-error compilings until you get it right. Search here for `[ffmpeg] is:answer disable-everything` and refer to `./configure --help`.